# Tokenize String Disregarding Trailing/Leading Whitespace

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I have to create a getToken function that will return one token at a time from the input buffer. I also need to implement an isWhiteSpace function that returns true if the character passed to it is white space (a blank, a tab, a line feed) and false if it is a CRLF or EOF.

My problem is that when I enter a string, it will only go to the first whitespace character and stop. If I start with a whitespace, it will just print a blank string. How can I fix this?

```
public class Lab1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Tokenizer!");
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Command: ");
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            String tk = getToken(s);
            if (tk.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(tk);
            }
        }
    }

    static String getToken(String w) {
        String b = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
            char c = w.charAt(i);
            if (!isWhite(c)) {
                b = b + c;
            } else {
                b = b + "";
                break;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }


    static boolean isWhite(char ch) {
        return (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`String.trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) ?

Comment: Hint: `break;` will stop any surrounding for-loop

Comment: You might not want to take a _break;_ from this exercise until you've read through all of the characters...

Comment: This is a non-trivial logic problem from your side - if you don't understand why the code is doing what it's doing, now would probably be as good a time as any to [learn to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). To figure out how to get the code to do what you want, you should probably sit down and figure it out in your head / on paper before writing any code.

Comment: @RC. Ah I see! But when I remove the break it ends up combining the tokens from  the whole string. How would I change it to where it prints each token on a separate line?

Comment: @lukas109 - So you know you don't want to return an empty token when you find whitespace so you probably don't want to break if your token string is empty, but you probably do if it isn't.  Also, adding an empty string ("") to an existing string doesn't change it at all so you can remove that logic.  The current logic you have will only return the first token per line so if you are going to have more than one token per line you will have to change your logic a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one token per line, your getToken method will have to be renamed to getTokens and return an ArrayList of Strings. 
Then you can loop through the tokens on the main method.
Here's a sample code with some suggested changes:

```
static ArrayList<String> getTokens(String w) {
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>(0);
    StringBuilder lastWord = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        char c = w.charAt(i);
        if (isWhiteSpace(c)) { // rename to isWhiteSpace, it's a more specific name
            tokens.add(lastWord); // if it's a white space add the last word to the list
            lastWord.clear(); // clear the buffer
        } else {
            lastWord.append(c); // append the char to the buffer
        }
    }
    // handle the last word
    if (lastWord.length() > 0) {
      tokens.add(lastWord);
    }
    return tokens;
}
```